# Can anyone explain the following slash notation?

Tags: notation

This notation can be seen made use of in equation 1.5 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.5200.pdf

Roughly speaking, $$\left. I = \int f(z) \prod_a \frac{dz^a}{z-z_a} \middle/ d\omega \right.$$  where $$d\omega = \frac{dz^1 dz^2 dz^3}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)} $$I do not understand what this slash notation means. Any examples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd wager that the slash is used to indicate the end of the argument for the product, indicating that $d\omega$ is for the integral, not the product.

Comment: Isn't it just division? Possibly in the form of a quotient space? Apparently we can divide out 3 dimensions, which is what that division seems to do.